# Javascript in CGI display error

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi, mojolicious

I do have this HTML code inside CGI program:

```
0  @@ process.html.ep
1  <% if ($errormsgs) { %>
2  <% for my $e (@$errormsgs){ %>
3  <%=$e%>
4  <br>
5  <% } %>
6  <a href="javascript:history.back();">Go back to fix the form</a><br>
7  <% } %>
8  <% if ($successmsg) { %>
9  <% for my $s (@$successmsg) { %>
10 <%=$s %>
11 <% } %>
12 <a href="<%= url_for('/') %>">Send another?</a><br>
13 <% } %>
```

so when line `1` is true, the line `12` doesn't print and that's what I want, but when line `1` is false, then line `6` print, but that shouldn't happen because I surrounded it with `if` statement brackets, so what I want is when `$errormsgs` is false, then `<a href="javascript:history.back();">Go back to fix the form</a><br>` shouldn't be displayed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$errormsgs` is most likely an empty arrayref, which always evaluates to true. Try this:

```
<% if (@$errormsgs) { %>
```